# "Cannot upload image bigger than 5mb" - Use image magick to convert image to max size of 5mg

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am getting the "Cannot upload file bigger than X mb" on a web form.
How can I use image magick to reduce an image down to a certain size in megabytes:

```
convert --min-size=4999KB --max-size=4999KB  my-img.jpg  my-img-resized.jpg
```

we can assume here that the image is bigger than 5MB, and I want to reduce it to 4999KB. How?

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out -define and in particular:

> jpeg:extent=value Restrict the maximum JPEG file size, for example
> -define jpeg:extent=400KB. The JPEG encoder will search for the highest compression quality level that results in an output file that
> does not exceed the value. The -quality option also will be respected
> starting with version 6.9.2-5. Between 6.9.1-0 and 6.9.2-4, add
> -quality 100 in order for the jpeg:extent to work properly. Prior to 6.9.1-0, the -quality setting was ignored.